# How to change the inputs inside an element within an array and divide the rest of a total number on the rest of the elements in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of inputs and I want to be able to change the amount inside each one separately after it's been created and have the remaining from a total figure divided by the the other inputs and added to them.

The number of inputs are created based on the user entry

I want to also be able to change more than one input Incase we don't want to divide the amount equally over the number entered by the user:

For example:

Total: 5000

<1000> -1

<1000> -2

<1000> -3

<1000> -4

<1000> -5

This will be auto populated (which I can do now)

But I want to be able to change for example -3 & -4 and have the remaining from the 5000 total divided equally into the inputs that I didn't change like so:

Total: 5000

<666.66> -1

<666.66> -2

<1500> -3

<1500> -4

<666.66> -5

// Here is my code so far:

```
// calculate monthly amount

const calculateMonthly = function () {
const late_fees_total = Number(numOfMonths) \* Number(lateFees);

const total_arrangement_amount = Number(overdue) + late_fees_total;

const amount_per_month =

  Number(total_arrangement_amount) / Number(numOfMonths) +

  Number(monthlyInstalment);

return amount_per_month;
};

// calculate total amount

const total_monthly_arrangement =
Number(calculateMonthly()) \* Number(numOfMonths);

  // ---------->>>> Creat input fields for months amounts
  for (let index = 0; index < numOfMonths; index++) {
    var month_input_ = document.createElement("INPUT");
    console.log(month_input_);
    const months_input_container = document.getElementById(
      "months-input-container"
    );
    month_input_.classList.add("months");
    months_input_container.append(month_input_);
  }

  // ===================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Add monthly amounts to monthly inputs
  const list_of_elements_months_inputs =
    document.getElementsByClassName("months");
  for (let i = 0; i < list_of_elements_months_inputs.length; i++) {
    list_of_elements_months_inputs[i].value = calculateMonthly().toFixed(2);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.